# making paint in pyqt or qt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, paint

i have just received a task to implement a software that paints over pictures (pretty much like microsoft paint )
i have no idea where to start or how to do that. do anyone have a good reference or idea for painting in qt or pyqt ?

this will be highly appreciated 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll be working with the [QImage class](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qimage.html), which represents bitmap images. It has methods for changing the colour at a given pixel using setPixel. There is am [Image Viewer Example](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/widgets-imageviewer.html) provided with Qt and PyQT should come with the same example in Python. However it uses a Qlabel to display the image so you may want to use a different widget, perhaps a custom QWidget subclass. You can start with that and add functionality to detect the mouse position in the , mouse clicks, etc and change the colours.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Qt painting class QPainter:
https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qpainter.html

Comment: QPainter is for vector drawing, not bitmaps as in MS Paint.

Comment: But you can easily achieve MS Paint functionality with QPainter. You can load QBitmap, create QPainter on it, draw what you need, and save it as bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the scribble example included in PyQt? It does basic drawing, saving, loading, etc.